VBA code to provide Option to create additionalrecord
I have a DB that collects input via a Form "Abgabe_Unterlagen" into a Table "Abgabe_Unterlagen."Structure and Form are attached.
The idea is to add records to the table "Abgabe_Unterlagen" so that the secretary can always identify which specialist has which records checked out.
As there are different types of records, it can happen that a customer turns in several different records.
I use the option in below code, that if the record for that customer already exists in that table, a msg box informs accordingly and let the user create an additional record.
I'm looking for a solution that will
a. use the value of the customer name already depict in the ComboBox "Mandantensuche" and copies it into the Field "Mandant_Name" in the Form.
b. It would be great if there could be a "Yes / No" option in the MsgBox to either to show and overwrite the existing record or to create an additional new one for this customer.
    Private Sub MandantenSuche_AfterUpdate()
   ' Den mit dem Steuerelement übereinstimmenden Datensatz suchen.     
     Me.Recordset.FindFirst "Mandant_Nummer_F = " & MandantenSuche
       If Me.Recordset.NoMatch Then
          MsgBox "Nichts gefunden. Bitte neu eingeben.", vbInformation
          DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
          DoCmd.GoToControl "Mandant_Name"
     Else: MsgBox "Mandant gefunden, zusätzliche Akte eingeben...", vbInformation
          DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
          DoCmd.GoToControl "Mandant_Name"
          'MandantName = MandantenSuche.Value
          'Mandant_Name.Value = MandantName
       End If
End Sub

Private Sub MandantenSuche_Enter()
    Me.MandantenSuche = Me.Mandant_Nummer
    'DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acFirst
    End Sub

can anybody help to get me on track ?
v/r
Banyan


OK, but what is your problem with this code?

Hi Gustav, none with this part...I`m just trying to find an elegant way
that if the record for that customer already exists in that table, a msg box informs accordingly and then opens the option to either overwrite the record or create an additional new one for this customer ...in this case .... do an ACNew and copy the t the customername and number into the new record, so the secretary can keep editing and create an additional customer record

If stay: go to the existing record. If new: set DefaultValue for customer name and number and go to a new record.

This is what I tried:
Private Sub Zusaetzl_Unterlagen_Click()
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Me.Mandant_Nummer.Value = rst("Mandant_Nummer")
Me.Mandant_Name.Value = rst("Mandant_Name")
' open New Record and Copy Mandant Namae
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
rst("Mandant_Nummer") = Me.Mandant_Nummer.Value
rst("Mandant_Name") = Me.Mandant_Name.Value
End Sub

Can't update a recordset that way. Not even opening a recordset object. That doesn't show any attempt at Gustav's suggestion. Should probably edit your question with attempted code and results.

Add an Else to your code then use another If Then to ask user which way they want to proceed.

OK thank you for leading me in the direction. ,I've added the else statement an edited the post with the new code and question. But can't come up with the coding for the further options...would be able to get me some further lead ?

As I said, add another If Then Else block below the first Else. If MsgBox ... = vbYes Then ... Else .... End If.

You can try something like this :
Private Sub MandantenSuche_AfterUpdate()

    ' Den mit dem Steuerelement übereinstimmenden Datensatz suchen.
    Me.Recordset.FindFirst "Mandant_Nummer_F = " & MandantenSuche
    '
    If Me.Recordset.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "Nichts gefunden. Bitte neu eingeben.", vbInformation
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        DoCmd.GoToControl "Mandant_Name"
    Else
        If vbYes = MsgBox("Neu eingebe ?", vbYesNo) Then
        
            DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
            DoCmd.GoToControl "Mandant_Name"
            'MandantName = MandantenSuche.Value
            'Mandant_Name.Value = MandantName
        
        Else
            '
            'Do something else...
            '
        End If
    End If
    
End Sub


Mathias, thank you so much  for the answer and code sample...I'll try soonest - probably not before Monday and let you know...
Would you have a hint why the handover of the value from "MandantenSuche" combo to the field "MandantName" in the form does not work  ?
